# Connection of a program to a database when using c++

Tags: c++, sql-server, database

I'm writing a simple program to manage the contacts. Now, I want to ask how can I handle DB storage for the program?

Since the program is installed locally, and it goes in many different Windows operating system, how the Database storage and connectivity will be handled on the machines where no MS SQL Server is installed? How the portability and shipment is tackled?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use SQL Server specifically, then it has to be installed on the machine.

On the other hand, if all you need is to store some data and not necessarily a database, that could be done in an arbitrary way.

You could also use something like SQLite, which is an SQL database that can be stored in a single file and doesn't require a server running (meaning you can just access it from your program using the driver.)

Comment: Ooo, no I just need an storage system, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: You could also store the data in a format like JSON or XML, which already have existing parsers. That way you could avoid having to write your own parser for a custom data format.